# SQL Query to select all sub folders

Tags: mysql, sql

So i have got these 2 tables;

### Folder

- folderID
- name

### folderFolder

- accountID
- parentFolderID
- childFolderID

folderFolder is basically a linking table that links sub folders with folders. now what i basically trying to do is select all sub folders linked to a selected folder.

Let say i have this folder hierarchy;

```
First Folder (this folder has id of 112)
  - Second Sub Folder 1
      - Third Sub folder of Second Sub Folder 1
  - Second Sub Folder 2
```

and i want to get the first folder with all of its sub folders.. i did this till now but it only gets the Second Sub Folders

```
SELECT * 
FROM folderFolder ff 
INNER JOIN folder f 
ON f.folderID = ff.childFolderID 
WHERE ff.ParentFolderID='112'
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: In your folder hierarchy what are the other ids?

Comment: il give you an example of records; record1 --
accountID-1
parentFolderID-112
childFolderID-113
record 2 --
accountID-1
parentFolderID-113
childFolderID-114

Comment: childfolder and parentfolder are both linked with folder table that is where the folder exists

Comment: Both parent and child have a corresponding id in Folder?

Comment: yes they both have corresponding id in folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try joining again:

```
SELECT *
FROM folderFolder ff 
INNER JOIN folderFolder ff_child
ON ff_child.parentFolderID = ff.childFolderID
INNER JOIN folder f
ON f.folderID = ff.childFolderID OR f.folderID = ff_child.childFolderID
WHERE ff.parentFolderID='112'
```

BTW '112' shouldn't be quoted if parentFolderID is numeric.

Comment: well this query is for my php assignment and i had a variable inside those quotes

Comment: ok this worked, so lets say i want to delete those selected queries; il just do... DELETE ff, ff_child, f right?

Comment: Glad it worked. Don't see why having a PHP variable means you need to use quotes... but anyway to answer your q, yes you can use that syntax in MySQL if you want to delete the specified data from all those tables. There are a couple of examples in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It will fetch any level of sub directories..

```
select parentFolderId, childFolderId, @parentFolderId:=childFolderId curr_child, f.folderId, f.name from folderFolder ff inner join folder f on f.folderId=ff.childFolderId;
```